# Calculate column amount and get total with order number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to calculate each order number amount and total amount with SQL status

```
Order_no    Status Amount
9008258656  P      50.00
9008258656  P      0.00
9008510713  P      50.00
9008510713  P      0.00
```

Comment: `select Order_no, sum(Amount) from T group by Order_no`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you want a simple aggregated query :

```
SELECT order_no, count(*) number_of_orders, sum(amount) total_amount
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_no
```

If you need to filter on a specific status :

```
SELECT order_no, count(*) number_of_orders, sum(amount) total_amount
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'P'
GROUP BY order_no
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to keep your individual line numbers (i.e. 4 total records) and not have aggregates (i.e. 2 total records), you can use the sum window function.

```
SELECT ord.Order_no
     , ord.Status
     , ord.Amount 
     , TotalSum = SUM(ord.Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY ord.Order_no, ord.Status)
FROM Orders ord
```

This would produce the following result:

```
Order_no    Status  Amount  TotalAmount
9008258656  P       50.00   50.00
9008258656  P       0.00    50.00
9008510713  P       50.00   50.00
9008510713  P       0.00    50.00
```

Based off the example you provided, there probably is not much value in doing the sum over in this scenario. @GMB's response should suffice. However, there are a lot of cool things you can do with the sum window function such as running totals. For example, if you had an order date column, you can include after the `PARTITION BY ord.Order_no, ord.Status ORDER BY ord.Order_date` and this would give you a running sum of the amount that increments by each order. I.E:

```
Order_no    Order_date  Status  Amount  RunningTotal
9008258656  1/2/2019    P       50.00   50.00
9008258656  1/3/2019    P       0.00    50.00
9008258656  1/4/2019    P       50.00   100.00
9008258656  1/5/2019    P       0.00    100.00
```